# What is the protocol for allowing euthanasia in a medical facility?

Tags: treatment-options, practice-of-medicine, death, euthanasia

Not many places allow assisted suicide however, when they do, it's for 'special circumstances'. On the other hand, there have been reports of "healthy" individual's, euthanasia requests being granted. Albeit, that is thoroughly debatable as many still do not consider mental illnesses as a variable in defining if someone is or is not "healthy" - for some profound and ignorant reasoning.

Specifically, I am referring to **Belgium**. Similarly, other countries allow it, also i.e. Switzerland.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about the protocol for allowing euthanasia. Usually, you can just look this up in the text of the law.

[This is the text of the law from Belgium](http://www.ethical-perspectives.be/viewpic.php?LAN=E&TABLE=EP&ID=59), for example.

The treating doctor must:

- inform the patient clearly about their condition and treatment options
- have several conversations with the patient, being certain of the patient's constant suffering
- consult another physician, who must review the patient's medical records and the patient themselves
- if the patient is not expected to die of their disease, a psychiatrist must be consulted
- the patient's request must be in writing

And so on, those laws are way too long to summarize here. This will vary with country. Unless a doctor wants to be charged with some form of homicide, they need to comply with these laws.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.